# Saving images to Postgresql Java

Tags: java, image, postgresql

I'm trying to save an image in a postgresql table

```
//table schema
CREATE TABLE public.hp_xray_results
(
  patient_no character varying(70),
  xray_image bytea
)

java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = connectDB.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO hp_xray_results (patient_no,xray_image) VALUES(?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1, jTextField36.getText());

File file = new File(String.valueOf(jTable3.getValueAt(i, 4)));
FileInputStream fis=null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
}

pstmt.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int) file.length());
try {
    fis.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
}

pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

On running the above code, I get an exception. `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to bind parameter values for statement.`

What improvements can I make?

Comment: It was 2 in the code, made a mistake while typing

Answer (score 1):

Replace all your code with the following:

```
File file = new File(...);
String sql = "INSERT INTO hp_xray_results (patient_no,xray_image) VALUES(?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connectDB.prepareStatement(sql);
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    pstmt.setString(1, jTextField36.getText());
    pstmt.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int) file.length());
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Documentation links:

- [Storing Binary Data](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/binary-data.html)
- [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)